# Canonical link in head of home page on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, head, canonical-link

I'm trying to have a line in the head of my home page for my rails site.  This should be:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://negotiatus.com" />
```

On my personal dev copy of the site, it appears perfectly in the head of the home page.  However, on the production version of the site it does not.  I believe it has something to do with Rails precompiling stuff, but I could be wrong.

If someone could point me in the right direction here that would be great

Relevant part of the home view:

```
<% content_for :for_head do %>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://negotiatus.com" />
<% end %>
```

In my application.html.erb:

```
<% if content_for? :for_head %>
<%= yield :for_head %>
<% end %>
```

It shows up if I inspect the source of my local dev copy, but doesn't show up if I view the source of the production version (hosted on heroku).

Comment: Show your layout code.

Comment: done, added the relevant parts

Comment: Now it works... sorry to waste time

Answer (score 0):

I retried precompiling everything, then committed and pushed everything again, now it works.

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.